# Force accounts.google.com instead of localised domain for oauth flow

Tags: oauth, google-oauth

We use OAuth from various providers to allow users to sign in and gain internet access through our public wifi.

In order to do this, we whitelist specific domains (e.g. accounts.google.com, api.twitter.com, etc) during the sign-in process and restrict everything else.

Recently, Google has started to redirect the user to a localised domain once they have signed in (e.g. accounts.google.co.uk) which is throwing a "Cannot Verify Server Identity" certificate error in the browser because the domain isn't whitelisted.

It is infeasible for us to add every possible localised Google domain to our whitelist, so is it possible to force Google OAuth to complete the full sign-in on accounts.google.com before returning the user to our OAuth endpoint?